# Read data from memory

Tags: c, exception, pointers

I have an API to read data:

ROM_READ_PAGE(BLOCK_NO, PAGE_NO, *READ_BUFFER);

The Page size is 2048 and you can ONLY read WHOLE page at a time.

I know it is just about using C, but my system doesn't run using either of the methods I tried.

For example:

```
char *readPtr;
char readBuff[128]; //(Can not use 2048 due to stack overflow)

readPtr = readBuff;

ROM_READ_PAGE(BLOCK_NO, PAGE_NO, readPtr); // SMX doesn't like this and shows some exception
```

Any other idea or if I am missing something important.

Comment: It is recommended to add the exception to your post.

Comment: Can you instead allocate memory on the heap (with `malloc`)? You said yourself that the page size is 2048 in size and you have to read whole page at once.

Comment: @pmg // SMX doesn't like this and shows some exception., Remember to scroll right :)

Comment: With the code as written, C doesn't guarantee you get any kind of good error result.  There is no way for ROM_READ_PAGE to know that readPtr doesn't point to enough memory -- it's going to copy a bunch of bytes all over your stack (and apparently past it).

Comment: @Joe: Ah! I see :) @Punit: `C` has no exceptions. Is the SMX compiled with a `C++` compiler perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

If your stack can't be 2048, that doesn't mean that you are excused from providing a 2048 byte block

```
char *readPtr = malloc(2048);
ROM_READ_PAGE(BLOCK_NO, PAGE_NO, readPtr);
// do whatever you need
free(readPtr);
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc() in C.

Comment: So, there is no way I can avoid reading less then 2048? It is an embedded system so wanted to avoid dynamic memory. However, it works.

Comment: @unwind done.  I had done it that way at first, then changed it.  You can edit answers to make them better.

Comment: @Punit -- Your description of ROM_READ_PAGE and its parameters don't allow for partial read.  Are there other API calls in the documentation that do partial reads?  Google searches for ROM_READ_PAGE turn up nothing and I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically allocate the buffer and avoid the stack overflow. you will also need to free the buffer

```
char *readBuff;
readBuff = (char *) malloc(2048);
free(readBuff);
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc() in C.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the stack.
If you compiler uses the stack for auto variables, you can either change the way your compiler deals with auto variables (unlikely) or use some other kind of variable.

Usually, compilers put static storage variables in a different area than auto variables. You may want to try that.

Or, try dynamic memory allocation.